# Linux command: find files and run command on them

Tags: linux, command-line

How do I manage to find all files in a directory and subdirectories and run a command on them?

For example,

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt"
```

finds all txt files and:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | gedit
```

sends it to gedit, but inside a text file. I want gedit to open all text files.

Answer (score 64):

You can use the `-exec` flag to execute a command on each matching file:

```
$ find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec gedit "{}" \;
```

#### Syntax

The syntax is a bit strange (see `-exec command ;` in the manpages for more):

```
The string `{}' is replaced by the current file name being processed
```

---

You may also want to consider `-execdir`, which will do the same, but executes the command from the subdirectory containing the matched file (this is generally preferable).

Comment: Thanks. I see that it works. But what does the end ("{}" \:) means? execute list?

Comment: The `{}` stands in for the current file name, and the semicolon is just terminating the command. The backslash and the surrounding quotes are just to prevent shell expansion.

Comment: I used a similar syntax to trace through a large file hierarch with multiple git repositories to find out if any files had been modified with `find . -iname ".git" -execdir git status \;` which looks for any directory that contains a hidden file named `.git` and then performs `git status` in that directory where the file was found. This finds all of the Git repositories in the file hierarchy and performs a `git status` on that repository to tell me if anything has changed. Left off the `\;` the first time and the command failed. Added it to the end and work great. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

`find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 gedit`

Comment: Thanks. I see that it works. But what does the -print0 | xargs -0 part means?

Comment: @xyz, you can read about the flags of _any_ UNIX command using the man pages. Try `man find` or `man xargs`, then `/` to search for a given flag. The documentation is quite good, it should answer your questions.

Comment: `-print0` prints a NULL character after each entry, `-0` expects entries to be separated by NULL character. It is the safest way to handle tricky names.

Comment: And isn't it a little bit strange that the syntax is not gedit xargs -0 instead of xargs -0 gedit. I see that the former doesn't work, but fail to see why.

Comment: `xargs` is a command that gets the data from the previous command on the pipe. It collects them and executes the `gedit` command with that datas. The thing you said means to run the `gedit` command with args `xargs` and `-0`.

Comment: xargs is preferable to -exec for performance reasons since xargs can "batch up" a number of arguments before passing them to gedit. If one needed to run gedit against each file individually, replace '... -print0 | xargs -0 gedit' with '... -print0 | xargs -0 -i gedit {}'

xargs is one of those commands like find and screen that you never know how you got along without a year after you learn about it.

Answer (score 3):

If the input argument to the command also needs manipulation, use "-I":

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.ext" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv "{}" "{}.txt"
```

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.